# Fetching user from friends list and follow list

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on social networking site. 
I've three tables one is user table which is used to store user details, another table is follow table which is used for followers following list.
 In this table I am storing user_id and follower_id. 
Third table is user_friends in this I'm storing user_id and friend_userid. 
I want to search the user from my friends list and follow list. For this i've written query like this:-

```
select f.follower_id,uf.friend_userid,u.user_id,u.first_name,u.last_name from tbl_user u 
LEFT JOIN tbl_userfriends uf ON uf.friend_userid = u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN tbl_follow f ON f.follower_id = u.user_id 
where uf.friend_userid != '11' 
AND u.first_name LIKE '%a%'
```

This query returning users only who are friends it is not returning the follow users.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Change "WHERE" to "AND" and change "AND" to "WHERE"

Answer (score 0):

You're joining `tbl_follow` on the Follower ID being equal to the User ID. I suspect that's probably not right.

If you don't already have one you'll need a user id key in the follower table to join on, then you can change your join to;

```
LEFT JOIN tbl_follow f ON f.userid = u.user_id
```

Comment: followers are users too.

Comment: if i m changing this then the name of follower is not coming in query result

Answer (score 0):

i've done this by using following query:-

select u.user_id,u.first_name,u.last_name from tbl_user u LEFT JOIN tbl_userfriends uf ON uf.friend_userid = u.user_id LEFT JOIN tbl_follow f1 ON f1.follower_id = u.user_id LEFT JOIN tbl_follow f2 ON f2.user_id = u.user_id where (uf.user_id = '11' OR f1.user_id = '11' OR f2.follower_id = '11') AND (u.first_name LIKE '%s%' OR u.last_name LIKE '%s%') AND u.status = '0' group by u.first_name 
This query returning me all the users who are my followers, friends and to whom i am following.